# Why does my C program only read 1 printf function?

Tags: c

There was no error display on my C compiler but I just can't get why the program would not read the printf function which is to run "Enter a mark for ___" so that I can enter data in. This happened so I could not load the .lst file nor .txt file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
     FILE *fin, *fout;//fin+fout are file pointers/handlers
    char name[100];
    float mark;
   
    fin = fopen("saved.lst", "r");//open in read mode as an ascii file

    if (fin == NULL) 
    {
        printf("file can't be opened for reading\n");
        return -1;
    }
    fout = fopen("updated.txt", "w");
    if (fin == NULL) 
    {
        printf("file can't be opened for reading\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while (fscanf (fin, "%s",&name) == 1)
{
     printf("Enter a mark for %s: ", name);
       scanf ("%f", &mark);
       fprintf(fout, "%s: %f",name, mark ); //formats & displays the data
       //close the file
     fclose(fout);}
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your question, but it appears you copy/pasted the null check for `fin` to use for `fout` and forgot to change the variable and the message.

Comment: You don't really want to `fclose(fout);` in the loop, do you?

Comment: I get `warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat=]` on your `fscanf` call.

Comment: There is just one problem with your code is you missed things. Just try to read line by line debug yourself, it will be good for you as a programmer as well as you will start feeling the mistakes you did were easy to debug.

Comment: You only need ONE `printf()` because neither `printf("file can't be opened for reading\n");` or `printf("file can't be opened for reading\n");` involve a type-conversion and can both simply have the `'\n'` removed and be output with `puts()`. Or, more properly, in both cases leave the `'\n'` and use `fputs()` outputting the error on `stderr`. Also note you error testing `if (fin == NULL)` twice (the 2nd could be `fout`) Avoid copy / paste errors.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled and fixed the errors. As per the comments: fclose(fout) should be below the while loop and fin should be closed there also. In fscanf &name should be just name. In fprintf, you probably want to output a \n at the end of the line. (I ran it with a few names each on a new line for saved.lst and checked that a mark had been added in updated.txt).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fin, *fout; // fin + fout are file pointers/handlers
    char name[100];
    float mark;
   
    fin = fopen("saved.lst", "r"); // open in read mode as an ascii file
    if (fin == NULL) 
    {
        printf("file fin can't be opened for reading\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fout = fopen("updated.txt", "w");
    if (fout == NULL)
    {
        printf("file fout can't be opened for writing\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fscanf (fin, "%s", name) == 1)
    {
         printf("Enter a mark for %s: ", name);
         scanf ("%f", &mark);
         fprintf(fout, "%s: %f\n", name, mark); //formats & displays the data
    }
    // close the files
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```